# How to pass a function with missing arguments?

Tags: c++, c, function

I have a procedure which takes `double (*function)(double t, double y)` as an argument. Now I have a function like `double fce (double t, double y, int a)` and I want to pass it to my procedure with one filled argument, something like `fce (, , 5)` to make it `double fce (double t, double y)` but I cannot find a way to do it in C or C++.

Comment: What do you want a solution for? C or C++? If it's C++ 11 you might find a solution using lambdas.

Comment: It's very easy in C++, almost impossible in C. For C++ read about [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). For C, you can make a wrapper function.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages in that aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (because you asked C or C++), you can do this with [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314972/the-purpose-of-function-binding/27315561#27315561) for more details.

```
using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, _3...
// Fix first argument as 10
auto fce_third_arg_is_5 = bind(fce, 5, _3);
/* foo(function); */
foo(fce_third_arg_is_5);
```

---

In [c](/questions/tagged/c), you can do this by writing a new converter function

```
/* Can be used only in global scope */
#define GEN_FUNC(X) double templated_fn_##X(double t, double y) {return fce(t, y, X);}

GEN_FUNC(5);
...
/* foo(function); */
foo(templated_fn_5);
```

Or a generic solution:

```
static int a_val_g;

static double wrapper(double t, double y)
{
  return fce(t, y, a_val_g);
}

function make_func(int a) {
  /* Warning: Not thread safe. Subsequent call will invalidate previously returned function */
  /* fn(make_func(i), make_func(42); is bad */
  /* Using make_func in a multithreaded application is unsafe unless synchronized properly */
  a_val_g = a;
  return wrapper;
}
...
/* foo(function); */
foo(make_func(5));
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, it is not. I should have added a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Look into writing a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), perhaps, which should get you the ability to pass different numbers of values.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are very different languages in that aspect.

You probably want a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (or if -like in C or old C++98- you don't have them, have a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) mechanism so pass both a function pointer and some additional data)

In C++, you need to use the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard (e.g. with `g++ -std=c++11`) atr least, which provides anonymous [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) -there are *closures*- and  [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) template

BTW, closures (and anonymous functions) are extremely convenient, and [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages sort-of need a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) to handle them conveniently. Such things are *much* easier to code in e.g. Ocaml, Clojure, Common Lisp, Haskell, etc....